# Custom popup for windows phone 8-1

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8.1, popup

I am working with windows phone 8-1[RT] application, I want to create custom popup like [iOS](https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView) I search lot in net but not found anything for that . Is there any other way to create custom popup which is used in entire application?

Another think I want to give popup to TOP-DOWN animation.

Answer (score 0):

if you create a storyboard in blend ?? Add your xaml one container control and put inside everything you want (loading , text etc) and add your storyboard on your control . I don't know if you can create one similar with IOS but you can try .

Comment: Thank you G.Mich for your reply , have you any example or reference regarding this ? Please share if you have

Comment: Check this http://www.janaks.com.np/custom-pop-up-dialog-box-in-windows-phone-8-1/